# Pandas date range inlcuding start date of series

Tags: python, pandas, date-range

```
dRan1 = pd.date_range(start ='1-15-2018', 
           end ='8-1-2018', freq ='M')
```

The code above generates the following series:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-31', '2018-02-28', '2018-03-31', '2018-04-30',
              '2018-05-31', '2018-06-30', '2018-07-31'],
               dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')
```

But I would like to have this:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-15', '2018-01-31', '2018-02-28', '2018-03-31', 
               '2018-04-30','2018-05-31', '2018-06-30', '2018-07-31'],
               dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')
```

Any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I think below can be one solution,

```
pd.date_range(start='1-15-2018', end='1-15-2018').union(pd.date_range(
start='1-15-2018',end='8-31-2018', freq='M', closed='right'))
```

Answer (score 1):

May be a custom function:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd
def myfunc(s,e):
    #check if start date is monthend
    if pd.to_datetime(s).date()==(pd.to_datetime(s)+ MonthEnd(0)).date(): 
        return pd.date_range(s,e, freq ='M') #dont append
    else: #else
        return pd.date_range(s,e, freq ='M').insert(0,pd.to_datetime(s)) #insert the date
```

---

*Test Runs:*

```
myfunc('1-15-2018','8-1-2018')
#DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-15', '2018-01-31', '2018-02-28', '2018-03-31',
#           '2018-04-30', '2018-05-31', '2018-06-30', '2018-07-31'],
#          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')
```

---

```
myfunc('1-31-2018','8-1-2018')
#DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-31', '2018-02-28', '2018-03-31', '2018-04-30',
#           '2018-05-31', '2018-06-30', '2018-07-31'],
#          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')
```

Comment: it is showing error on insert,<< ValueError: Inferred frequency None from passed dates does not conform to passed frequency M >>

Answer (score 0):

You can add the first date using the `insert` function.

```
dRan1.insert(0, pd.to_datetime('2018-01-15'))
DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-15', '2018-01-31', '2018-02-28', '2018-03-31',
               '2018-04-30', '2018-05-31', '2018-06-30', '2018-07-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')
```

However, the spacing between your dates is not uniform then, so just think whether this is useful.

Comment: It will be used with reindex function, and my start date in current index is 15-01-2018, then few month end dates. reindex will fill missing end date rows from previous row.